# Other Things to replace on my van while doing the valve cover gasket

Tags: ford, valve-cover, van, econoline

Was going to replace the valve cover gasket on my 1989 Econoline with 67k mile. it's a bit of a pain to get in there, is there anything else I should be looking at, or replacing while I'm in there?

Comment: This question is too broad. You should provide a list of items you will be removing during the valve cover gasket replacement. That way other contributors could indicate if the item is worth replacing at the same time.